# Awk, Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file which has the following form:

```
#id|firstName|lastName|gender|birthday|creationDate|locationIP|browserUsed
111|Arkas|Sarkas|male|1995-09-11|2010-03-17T13:32:10.447+0000|192.248.2.123|Midori
```

Every field is separated with "|". I am writing a shell script and my goal is to remove the "-" from the fifth field (birthday), in order to make comparisons as if they were numbers.

For example i want the fifth field to be like |19950911|

The only solution I have reached so far, deletes all the "-" from each line which is not what I want using sed.

i would be extremely grateful if you show me a solution to my problem **using awk**.

Comment: Do you want - replaced with anything ?

Comment: @ArifBurhan I want the fifth field to be like |19950911|

Comment: read about AWK's `gsub` function

Comment: You do not need to remove the `-`s since a string comparison of `YYYY-MM-DD` will produce the same relative order as a numeric comparison of `YYYYMMDD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An **awk** one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { gsub("-","",$5); print }' infile.txt
```

Comment: Yes that finally worked. But I want to ask one more thing. At the command you wrote if i write:

awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" } { gsub("-","",$5); print **$1,"|",$2** }' infile.txt

The result is "Whatever $1 is" "blank" "|" "blank" "Whatever $2 is".

How do i remove blank spaces?

Comment: Remove the commas: `print $1 "|" $2`.  OR you can set `OFS`: `BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"} {gsub...; print $1, $2}`. Note that when you set `OFS` (output file separator) you keep the commas, but don't explicitly print the `|`.

Comment: That was very helpful. I appreciate it.

Comment: You can define OFS value as "|"

Answer (score 3):

If this is a homework writing the complete script will be a disservice.  Some hints: the function you should be using is `gsub` in awk. The fifth field is `$5` and you can set the field separator by `-F'|'` or in `BEGIN` block as `FS="|"`

Also, line numbers are in `NR` variable, to skip first line for example, you can add a condition `NR>1`

Comment: My problem is that I speek Greek and I can't find proper gsub documentation that i can understand. The homework task is only this so it is a "one-line" solution that's why I did not write the full script.

Answer (score 1):

To keep "|" as output separator, it is better to define OFS value as "|" :

```
... | awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|"} {gsub("-","",$5); print $0 }'
```